# USB Keyboard doesn't work server installation 12.10

Tags: installation, server, 12.10, usb, keyboard

USB Keyboard doesn't work server installation 12.10. I can get till the language selection screen and later no response to keyboard. Need help.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's not much info to go on I'll give some general troubleshooting tips.
Try:
-Using a different usb port
-Turning the computer off and on
-Using a different keyboard, if you have one, to see if it's the computer's fault

That's the best I can give you. More info on the computer(laptop or desktop, previous OS's etc.) and the keyboard(has it worked before, does it work on other computers etc.) would be appreciated for a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for "USB Legacy Support" in your motherboard's BIOS options.  Setting this to "on" may be necessary in order to get the keyboard working before the OS is fully booted.

Sadly, it may also be necessary to plug in a PS/2 keyboard to GET to the BIOS options in the first place... but usually (usually!) not.